# Solving Ratio Dependent ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given $$x' = \frac{2x+3t} {4x-5t}$$ being ratio dependent how do you go about solving?

I get the following to start 
$$ u = \frac{x}{t}, x=tu, x'=u+tu' $$
$$ x'= \frac{2+3\frac{t}{x}}{4-5\frac{t}{x}} $$
$$ x'= \frac{2+\frac{3}{u}}{4-\frac{5}{u}} $$

$$ u+tu'= \frac{2+\frac{3}{u}}{4-\frac{5}{u}} $$
$$ t\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{2+\frac{3}{u}}{4-\frac{5}{u}} -u $$
$$ \int\frac{du*4-\frac{5}{u}}{2+\frac{3}{u}}+u = \int\frac {dt}{t}$$

Giving me

$$ 1/8 (15+16 u+4 u^2-44 ln(3+2 u)) = ln|t|+C $$

resubstituting x in for u

$$ 1/8 (15+16 \frac{x}{t}+4 \frac{x}{t}^2-44 ln(3+2 \frac{x}{t}))= ln|t|+C $$

Would this be correct and then to find C if given initial values I'd just plug in those values?

Answer (score 2):

HINT :

$$ t\frac{du}{dt} = \frac{2+\frac{3}{u}}{4-\frac{5}{u}} -u = \frac{3+7u-4u^2}{4u-5}$$
$$ \int\frac{4u-5}{3+7u-4u^4} du = \int\frac {dt}{t}$$

Comment: Not sure how you got. $$\frac{3+7u-4u^2}{4u-5}$$

Comment: $ \frac{2+\frac{3}{u}}{4-\frac{5}{u}} -u =  \frac{2u+3}{4u-5} -u =  \frac{2u+3}{4u-5} -\frac{u(4u-5)}{4u-5} =\frac{2u+3-u(4u-5)}{4u-5}  = \frac{3+7u-4u^2}{4u-5}$